# List of characters and digits

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What's the best way of defining a list of characters that consist of the following: `a-z`, `A-Z`, and `0-9`? I really wanted to avoid typing one huge array to hold this data, how can I accomplishing this in Bash? In Python, this list of data can be joined as such:

```
for i in xrange(length):
    password += random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)

print password
```

Comment: a list you mean, a string? `a b c d...`?

Comment: I would like to define a list of all lowercase and uppercase letters ranging from a-z, plus the digits 0-9. @Kent

Comment: there is no `list` data structure in bash. anyway, I posted an answer. hope it helps.

Comment: did you google it? I just queried "bash password generator", it gave me this: legroom.net/2010/05/06/bash-random-password-generator It creates the array that you want (`CHAR="[:alnum:]"`), and it also generates a random password... what do you need that is different from that?

Comment: Yes, I wanted my own personal script to do handle this for me. @Kent pointed me in the right direction. Thanks for all of the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you really need an array for this, just a string (since it's easy to pick the n'th character out of a string):

```
printf -v chars "%s" {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9}
nchars=${#chars}
for ((i=1; i<=length; i++)); do
    password+="${chars:RANDOM%nchars:1}"
done
```

Comment: You've definitely given me some more ideas and a clearer idea as to what I need to do next, I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 4):

if the `list` you meant is a string, you could:

**Bash**

```
kent$ echo {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9}
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

**zsh**

```
kent$  echo {a-z} {A-Z} {0-9}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

**EDIT**

OP wants an array:

```
kent$ arr=( {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9} )
kent$ echo ${arr[@]}
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
kent$ echo ${arr[3]}
d
```

Comment: Not exactly, I'm trying to generate a random password, but before doing this I need an array of all of those characters to manipulate. I'm hoping I can avoid typing this huge array.

Comment: so you need a `bash array`?

Comment: @Dford.py see my EDIT for an array

Answer (score 1):

Generate an array this way:

```
array=( ); 
i=0; 
for c in {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9}; do 
    array+=("$c"); 
    let i++; 
done
```

Comment: I think this nails it, I could even delegate {a..z}{A..Z}{0..9} in a variable.

Comment: The loop is unnecessary; just put the brace expressions directly in the parentheses when you assign to `array`.